# Efficient way to customize UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

What is the best way to customize the look of UIButtons in an app? I am working on an app where we programatically update UIButtons to look the way we want. Most of the buttons are created in Interface Builder and we want to execute our `customizeButton`-method on them in an efficient way. I only see two ways of achieving this:

1. Create the buttons in IB, assign them to an outlet and in code call `customizeButton` for each button.
   **Problem:** way too much hazzle
2. Subclass UIButton, in the constructor `initWithCoder:` call `customizeButton`. Then use this class for buttons in IB.
   **Problem:** allthough this works for buttons created in IB and requires less boilerplate code than point 1, I have read all the warnings against subclassing UIButton because of their class cluster.

Clearly there must be some better way, what is point 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at UIAppearance. It is available since iOS 5 and is especially for customizing the standard UI elements.

For ever class that is customizable is a class method called `+appearance:` and you can use it like this.

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Every button will have now a red background color.

To get started have a look at Ray Wenderlichs Tutorial [User Interface Customization in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) and/or session `114 - Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls` of the WWDC11 videos.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Out of curiosity, were there any good alternatives prior to iOS 5?

Comment: I guess subclassing would be the way